# Generate ID or class for each title in WordPress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, id-generation

So I have the code below for my website in WordPress. Under that it shows the title of the current page for example, mine is "Baby"(in black). So I would like to have a unique class or ID for each title (so I can have a different color for each title instead of black for all) but since they are generated by PHP I do not know to to achieve this. If it was a pure HTML I could just give a class and style it but now I do not have any unique class.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

   <div class="primary-content">

          <?php 
       // display taxonomy info

 themedsgn_biancca_taxonomy_info();

// initiate the blogroll type
$blogroll_type = get_theme_mod( 'themedsgn_setting_archive_layout', 'grid' );

if( have_posts() ) {

    echo '<div class="blogroll blogroll-' . $blogroll_type . ' cf">';

    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', $blogroll_type );
    }

    echo '</div>';

    // pagination
    themedsgn_biancca_post_pagination();

} else {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
}
?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: your title is generated with  themedsgn_biancca_taxonomy_info(); right? ithink you should post that piece of code

Comment: yes it is..I really do not know where to get that from

Answer (score -1):

Look in Appearance/Editor, then look for the file called archive.php. Then search for archive-title. It should be in there.

Comment: This is a screenshot from one of my sites archive headers. http://screencast.com/t/HoiLi9Ri